# OSStatus error 2003334207 while re-buiding the App from Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode6, avaudioplayer

I am using AVAudioPlayer to play recorded audio which is saved in Iphone's Document directory.
When I first record an audio and then play, it works fine (Device is connected to the system and App is running through Xcode).

But when I Stop the running App through Xcode and again run the App through Xcode, I am getting Error `Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=2003334207 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 2003334207.)"`

File Location: `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/410AB24E-5FB0-4401-AC59-3C03D676E951/Documents/26-06-2015--13:10:47.m4a`

My Code:

```
fileLocation = @"file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/410AB24E-5FB0-4401-AC59-3C03D676E951/Documents/26-06-2015--13:10:47.m4a"

NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:fileLocation];
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileUrl error:&error];
[player setDelegate:self];

NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:fileName];
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileUrl error:&error];
[player setDelegate:self];
```

I am using Xcode 6 and running App in IOS 8

P.S: I have read so many documentations related to this issue and also several questions in statckoverflow itself, but I didn't find the answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Under iOS8, the path that you have saved won't be valid across launches.  The id you see "410AB24E-5FB0-4401-AC59-3C03D676E951" will change with each launch.

The solution is to save the filename and not the complete path, and to recreate the URL or complete path, by getting the path to the Documents (or tmp) folder and appending the filename to it.

Comment: Is that ID changes after every update of App OR device's OS?

Comment: After every launch of your app.  In other words, when your app terminates, and then is relaunched by the user (or when you are testing and you Run in Xcode), that ID will change.

Comment: It's easy to check.  Use `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);` to get the new path for the Documents directory.  Compare it to the last one you had.  It will be different overtime you launch your app.

Comment: Yes I've checked. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: @mahboudz Its not working for me. I have checked the file exists at path and I am using `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);` but still its giving me  error `The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 2003334207.)`

Comment: Check and make sure you are using a fileURL and not a plain URL.  Instead of `- URLWithString:`, use:  `- fileURLWithPath:isDirectory:`,  `- initFileURLWithPath:isDirectory:` or `+ fileURLWithPath:`

Comment: I have checked the code again `self.play(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: finalURLPath))`