# audioPlayer error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 2003334207.)

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I'm trying to use AvAudioRecorder to record some sound, then use AvAudioPlayer to play it.

This is the [code guide](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Recording_Audio_on_iOS_9_with_AVAudioRecorder) I'm currently using. I implemented all the codes in the page correctly, when I click play it gives me

> audioPlayer error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 2003334207.)

Any idea how to fix this? The ios I'm using is 9.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this is your problem: [OSStatus error 2003334207 while re-buiding the App from Xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31067989/osstatus-error-2003334207-while-re-buiding-the-app-from-xcode-6)

Also make sure that you are using a fileURL and not a plain URL.